# Как вести переписку с пользователями через телеграм бота , в библиотеке telebot ( python)

Tags: telebot

Например : у пользователя возникла проблема при использовании телеграм бота или у него есть вопросы, он нажимает на кнопку "Помощь" и подробно описывает свою проблему. Далее после изучения данной проблемы, администраторы должны написать ему ответ через конкретного бота. Как это сделать? , можете отправить пример с кодом в библиотеке telebot (python)